# drupal views_embed_view pass filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

print views_embed_view('VIEWNAME','default', '2011-01-01');

How can I pass values to the filters of a embedded view?
I am trying to pass a date value to the exposed date filter.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0):

If you don't embed the view's via PHP but rather with blocks, and if the exposed date filter is from one view, you can do this with the Relationships section of views. You add the view that has the date filter to the relationship of what was the embedded view. Then add an filter for the date field of the relationship view.

Comment: It would still be nice to know if there's some way to do this with views_embed_view.